# In Ansible how can i run a block of tasks in loop for limited number of times?

Tags: ansible

I have set of Ansible Playbook tasks which i would like to run in loop with a max limit (for instance, 3 times max if the condition is not satisfied). I have tried to use block but it doesn't allow `retries` and `until`.

How can i run the instructions in a loop with a condition and max number of iterations (if the condition is not satisfied)?

I have tried the following so far.

```
- hosts: all
  name: runLinuxSystemUpdate
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Set Facts if not present in Host.
      include: checkLinuxSystemUpdateStatusTask.yml
      when: ansible_facts['Missing_Hotfix_Patches'] is not defined or ansible_facts['Missing_Hotfix_Patches'] == ""

    - name: Iteration Block
      block:

        - name: Install Patches Block
          block:
            - name: Run InstallLinuxPatchesTask.yml Task File
              include: InstallLinuxPatchesTask.yml

          when: ansible_facts['Missing_Hotfix_Patches'] != '0' or ansible_facts['Missing_Security_Patches'] != '0'  

        - name: Reboot Machines Block
          block:
            - name: Run RebootLinuxMachinesTask.yml Task File
              include: RebootLinuxMachinesTask.yml

          when: ansible_facts['Pending_Reboot'] == true

        - name: Run checkLinuxSystemUpdateStatusTask task file to re-validate Update and Reboot Status
          include: checkLinuxSystemUpdateStatusTask.yml
          #when: update_result.stdout.find("The deployment of patches and packages was successfully") == -1

      until: ansible_facts['Missing_Hotfix_Patches'] != '0' and ansible_facts['Missing_Security_Patches'] != '0'
      retries: 3
```

Here, the task files run fine. I am not able to identify a way to run the instructions in `- name: Iteration Block` till the condition is fulfilled **or** the max retries/iterations are reached - whichever is first.

**Environment Details**

Ansible Version: Ansible 2.7.4
AWX Version: AWX 2.1.2.0 on Docker

Answer (score -5):

Please check the documentation about Loops in ansible
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

An easy way to loop is using a list

```
- name: add several users
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
    groups: "wheel"
  loop:
     - testuser1
     - testuser2
```

Or using `with_items`

```
- name: with_items
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ items }}"
```

Comment: I know about loops but i believe this would work for a single tasks. How can i make this work for a bunch of tasks or a block of tasks?

Comment: @AnkitVashistha, I stumbled upon same problem. Unfortunately, ansible doesn't support iterating through list over blocks (with_items) yet, [proof](https://shasawas.wordpress.com/2016/05/23/how-to-loop-over-a-set-of-tasks-in-ansible/). As a workaround author of previously mentioned article suggests to put block contents inside a subfile and iterate through the list of items with executing subfile contents like this:
` tasks:
    - include: includeFile.yml pkgName="{{item}}"
      with_items: packageList`